# improving a function to read files in a folder

Tags: r, function, data.table, readr

I built this function:

```
alterations <- function() {
  
  if (!require(readr)) {install.packages("readr")}
  if (!require(stringr)) {install.packages("stringr")}
  if (!require(data.table)) {install.packages("data.table")}
  
  temp <- list.files(pattern = "*_automat.lif")
  dados <- NULL
  
  for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
    
    df1 <- fread(file = temp[[i]],
                 select = c(1, 18),
                 col.names = c("name", "classificador"))[order(name)]
    
    df2 <-fread(str_remove(temp[[i]], "_automat"),
                select = c(1, 18),
                col.names = c("name", "validador"))[order(name)]
    
    tb1 <- cbind(df1[, 2], df2[, 2]) %>%
      table()
    
    df3 <- cbind(ciclo = temp[[i]],
                 validation_date = str_sub(file.info(temp[[i]])$mtime, 1, 10), 
                 as.data.table(tb1))
    
    dados <- rbind(dados, df3)
  }
  
  write_csv(dados, file = "dados_brutos.csv")
  return(dados)
  
}
```

I need help to improve this function:

1. I have a hundreds of files in a folder with the names as: aaa.lif, aaa_automat.lif, bbb.lif, bbb_automat.lif, ccc.lif, ccc.automat.lif, ... that have the same columns and a thousands of rows, but different values in some columns (as column 18, specified in the code). I need bind the columns column 18 (**classificador**) of these files for the same column 1 (**name**). However, some files has a problem and didn't have some rows in file *_automat.lif. I trying use `merge` in place of `cbind` to merge data.tables df1 and df2 by column **name** but time to execute the function was much worse.
2. I don't know if my for(){} if efficient, Is there a better way?

data example:

```
dput(df1)
setDT(structure(list(name = c("2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1009_1943.png", 
"2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1025_394.png", "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1077_1739.png", 
"2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1345_631.png", "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1360_1538.png", 
"2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1435_1340.png", "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1508_352.png"
), classificador = c("organism", "shadow", "coscinodiscus", "shadow", 
"shadow", "shadow", "shadow")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")))

dput(df2)
setDT(structure(list(name = c("2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1009_1943.png", 
    "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1025_394.png", "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1077_1739.png", 
    "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1345_631.png", "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1360_1538.png", 
    "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1435_1340.png", "2020-12-01_00_34_54.029_1508_352.png"
    ), validador = c("shadow", "shadow", "coscinodiscus", "shadow", 
    "shadow", "shadow", "shadow")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame")))
```

output:

```
                                                  ciclo validation_date classificador     validador N
1: Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat.lif      2021-07-09 coscinodiscus coscinodiscus 1
2: Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat.lif      2021-07-09      organism coscinodiscus 0
3: Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat.lif      2021-07-09        shadow coscinodiscus 0
4: Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat.lif      2021-07-09 coscinodiscus        shadow 0
5: Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat.lif      2021-07-09      organism        shadow 1
6: Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat.lif      2021-07-09        shadow        shadow 5
7: Basler_2020-12-01 01_35_01.902191_frames_automat.lif      2021-07-10        shadow        shadow 7
```

thank you

Comment: Can you provide some small sample data from df1, df2 and the expected output? Instead of the for loop I suggest to use lapply over each file. Something like this, to optimize the rest I need some sample data. `files <- list.files(pattern = "*_automat.lif")
dados <- lapply(files, function(file) {
  ## do all in the for loop
})
dados <- rbindlist(dados)
write_csv(dados, file = "dados_brutos.csv")`

Comment: I add part of data of 1 file of df1 and 1 file of df2 and their respective output.

Comment: I used the sample data to try to understand what happened in all your steps, I posted my answer which I think should do what you try to achieve on your files.

Comment: Iteratively `rbind`ing data technically works, but is inefficient in the long run: each time you `rbind`, it makes a complete copy of the data in memory. The first few times this will work without much delay, but as the number of iterations (and rows) goes up, each operation will take significantly longer than the previous. This falls within the "second circle" of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), read chapter two on *"Growing Objects"*. It's much better to keep the frames in a `list`, then later to `do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)` (or use `rbindlist`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this comes pretty close to what you try to achieve.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*_automat.lif")

dados <- lapply(files, function(file) {
  
  df1 <- fread(file = file, select = c(1, 18), col.names = c("name", "classificador"))
  df2 <- fread(str_remove(file, "_automat"), select = c(1, 18), col.names = c("name", "validador"))
  
  tbl <- merge(df1, df2)
  tbl[, ciclo := file]
  tbl[, validation_date := str_sub(file.info(file)$mtime, 1, 10)]
  tbl
  
})

dados <- rbindlist(dados)

dados[, name := NULL]
setcolorder(dados, c("ciclo", "validation_date", "classificador", "validador"))

# from the output it seems you want to group and show counts
dados <- dados[, .(N = .N), by = .(ciclo, validation_date, classificador, validador)]

write_csv(dados, file = "dados_brutos.csv")
```

Comment: I test this code with all of my data. With this improvements the time consumption increase in ~20 seconds. Although the `merge()` function solve my problem with the rows not coincidents in some files.

Comment: Is it possible to the increased in time to be due to `lapply()` function?

Comment: WilsonSouza, I don't think so, `lapply` should be adding nothing here. This approach is fairly straight-forward, though I suggest adding an explicit `by=` and `all.x=TRUE` to `merge` and/or using `data.table`'s `[`-merge methods (e.g., `df1[df2, validador := i.validador, on = .(name)]`, then no `merge(.)` call ... but only if a left-join is the desired operation).

Comment: I agree the merge could be more efficient, also you can try to apply twice, create datos1 and datos2 and join those at once in the end. Depending on your data you might need more than only the name to join on, but adding ciclo in both on reference is pretty fast to secure that. Not sure what will win in speed.

Comment: Just one more comment. Comparisons, where `N = 0` would appear, as in the lines 2, 3 and 4 in the output not appear.